# Making a new pandas dataframe with columns of the values of each id in a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
            timestamp    id  value
0 2020-09-27 10:00:00     a     10
0 2020-09-27 10:00:00     b     13
0 2020-09-27 10:00:00     c     16
0 2020-09-27 10:01:00     a     11
0 2020-09-27 10:01:00     b     14
0 2020-09-27 10:01:00     c     17
0 2020-09-27 10:02:00     a     12
0 2020-09-27 10:02:00     b     15
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame with columns of the value for each id at a certain timestamp.

```
                            a    b    c
2020-09-27 10:00:00        10   13   16
2020-09-27 10:01:00        11   14   17
2020-09-27 10:02:00        12   15  NaN
```

I've tried the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['timestamp'].unique())
for unique in df['id'].unique():
    df2 = df2.join(df[df['id']==unique]['value'])
    df2.rename(columns={"value": unique})
```

However, I get the following error: `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['value'], dtype='object')`

Can someone explain me what goes wrong and/or what would be a better way to get to the results?

Comment: you can do `df.pivot('timestamp', 'id', 'value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use df.[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df.pivot(index=['timestamp'], columns = ['id'], values = ['value']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [798]: df.pivot_table(values = 'value', index='timestamp', columns = 'id').reset_index()
Out[798]: 
id            timestamp     a     b     c
0   2020-09-27 10:00:00  10.0  13.0  16.0
1   2020-09-27 10:01:00  11.0  14.0  17.0
2   2020-09-27 10:02:00  12.0  15.0   NaN
```